# How to Customize Email Templates in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email-templates

I am trying to add subject to custom email template but it is not working.

Comment: How are you trying to add subject in email templates? Can you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to have this snippet at the top of your custom email template:

```
<!--@subject My Custom Email Template Subject @-->
```

app/code/[Vendor]/[ModuleName]/view/[{frontend|adminhtml}]/email/custom_email_template.html:

```html
<!--@subject My Custom Email Template Subject @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Example Content
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```